# How to properly remove Timer instance

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am using `Timer` instance in my project.

I create and add an instance to `RunLoop`

```
timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    print("Hello")
})

if let timer = timer {
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
}
```

Now I am thinking about how to properly stop and remove Timer:

1. Should I trust in ARC and don't care about it?
2. Maybe `deinit` implementation is need. If is it true, what should be inside

   ```
   deinit {
       longPressTimer?.invalidate()
       longPressTimer = nil
   }
   ```

`invalidate` is nesseccery? `= nil` ?

I have read serval threads from Stack about it but answers are contradictory. Could someone tell me which way is properly and explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both *invalidate()* and *= nil*. <s>Unlike other objects, a timer DOES NOT get deallocated when its retain count reaches zero unless it's stopped (invalidated).</s>

Say, if you have a repeating timer which is currently active. when you set timer = nil, it still persists in memory and keeps triggering the action (probably the iOS has some kinds of mechanism to keep it alive as long as it's still active). So the rule of thumb is: Always call invalidate() and  set the timer to nil when you want to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank for explanation. Could you link any official documentation about this?

Comment: You can read it here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer
"Run loops maintain strong references to their timers". That pretty much explains it.

Comment: According documentation `= nil` is not nesseccery because `Invalidating the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer affects the run loop. The run loop then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer), either just before the invalidate() method returns or at some later point.`

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking it's not necessary, it's only needed when the timer is stored inside an instance variable.

Comment: ARC will not do his job? In my opinion when timer is stored inside an instance variable it will deallocate when instance will deallocate. What do you think?

Comment: Good point, but calling invalidate() on a instance variable timer without setting it to nil will leave you an unused object in memory, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145864/discussion-between-kamil-harasimowicz-and-hoang-cap).

Comment: Don't think so. According documentation `invalidate()` will remove `timer` form `RunLoop` and ARC remove timer `variable` from my `class` when my `class` will deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

If timer is repeating it won't invalidate as long as it's target is in memory.

The best solution for me was to use this class - which will observe target, and it target is deallocate it will invalidate itself.

```
final class WeakTimer {
    private weak var timer: Timer?
    private weak var target: AnyObject?
    private let action: (Timer) -> Void

    private init(timeInterval: TimeInterval,
                     target: AnyObject,
                     repeats: Bool,
                     userInfo: Any?,
                     action: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) {
        self.target = target
        self.action = action
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(fire(timer:)), userInfo: userInfo, repeats: repeats)
        RunLoop.main.add(self.timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

    class func scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval,
                              target: AnyObject,
                              userInfo: Any?,
                              repeats: Bool,
                              action: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer {
        return WeakTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval,
                         target: target,
                         repeats: repeats,
                         userInfo: userInfo,
                         action: action).timer!
    }

    @objc fileprivate func fire(timer: Timer) {
        if target != nil {
            action(timer)
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether timer exist? if yes then invalidate it like

```
 if timer!= nil {
    timer.invalidate()
 }
```

Keep in mind that if you use a timer in any VC invalidate it when you leave that VC(View Controller)

Comment: We have `optional chain` in Swift. Your `if statement` is not necessary. I can call `timer?.invalidate()`. When `timer` will be `nil` `invalidate()` method will not call.